# Whether the relation $R = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,1), (1,3)\}$ is anti-symmetric or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

From my own understanding, a relation is anti-symmetric if it has $(a, b)$ but does not have $(b, a)$ while $(a, a)$ and $(b, b)$ are allowed.

But in my college textbook, the relation  $R = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (2,1), (1,3)\}$ is given as only reflexive and neither transitive nor anti-symmetric. I'm confused now.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You are right: your book is wrong indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is antisymmetric, if from $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$ with $x,y \in X$, follows that $x = y$, which is the case for your set $X$ and relation $R$. It is not transitive, since $(2,1) \in R$ and $(1,3) \in R$ but not $(2,3) \in R$.